# Embedding VB macro in python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I am new to use of win32com module . Following code i found on web for generating excel :

```
import win32com.client as win32
class generate_excel:
    def excel(self):
        excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        excel.Visible = True
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
        ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
        ws.Name = 'Share'
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(2,2),ws.Cells(2,3)).Value = [1,70]
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(3,2),ws.Cells(3,3)).Value = [2,90]
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(4,2),ws.Cells(4,3)).Value = [3,92]
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(5,2),ws.Cells(5,3)).Value = [4,95]
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(6,2),ws.Cells(6,3)).Value = [5,98]
        wb.SaveAs('hi.xlsx')
        excel.Application.Quit()            
d=generate_excel()
d.excel()
```

In this code i want to add a VB Script to draw a pie chart before the excel is closed . The VB Script is as follows :

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C2:C6")
End Sub
```

Please tell how to embed this in my Python Script .

Comment: Can you mark the answer if it solved your problem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit late and you've probably already found a solution but hopefully this helps someone else.

```
from win32com.client import DispatchEx

# Store vba code in string
vbaCode = """
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("C2:C6")
End Sub
"""

# Init Excel and open workbook
xl = DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(path_to_workbook)

# Create a new Module and insert the macro code
mod = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
mod.CodeModule.AddFromString(vbaCode)

# Run the new Macro
xl.Run("Macro2")

# Save the workbook and close Excel
wb.SaveAs(path_to_file, FileFormat=52)
xl.Quit()
```